# how to add superscripts in sqlite3

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm creating a database using SQLite 3. Many of my fields are gonna need superscripts and subscripts, e.g. a^2, (a+b)^2, etc. What do I need to do to be able to specify a subscript or superscript? I am using java to write my code for an android aplication.

Any examples demonstrating how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind: no, your fields do *not* need superscripts and subscripts. They just need unique names, and you can represent them on screen using whatever label you fancy. Or are you synchronizing with a third party database that already has such fields?

Answer (score 2):

> What do I need to do to be able to specify a subscript or superscript?

Choose a textual representation of your formulas (MathML, HTML with `<sup>` and `<sub>`) and store them in the database that way.

Comment: @PankajKushwaha: That would be because `someTextView` is `null`, apparently.

Comment: I am not able to store in databse. What should be data type of that column ? I used text and when i m trying to persist with superscript m unable to do so and I have to convert it to string only by doing which i loose my superscripts

Answer (score 2):

I used `form.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));` and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unicode superscript HTML entities.

http://theorem.ca/~mvcorks/cgi-bin/unicode.pl.cgi?start=2070&end=209F
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aUnicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)